# How to add token request in wordprses url

Tags: json

Adding the token request generated from jwt token in the worpress url, like the folliwng example
https://www.example.com/login/?tokenRequest=https://

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.